# CSS scrolling gallery won't let me add links

Tags: css, scroll

So I have this scrolling thumbnail gallery here:

http://www.thewiredlife.net/kelseytest/testing.html

It starts off great but as soon as the first image passes, the rest of them stop. This only happens when I add links to the images, which there needs to be.

This is just a test file so the CSS isn't external. Too lazy lol.

Any ideas to get them continuously scrolling?

Comment: Can you elaborate what we should be looking at? I don't see anything scrolling on your page.

Comment: As soon as you click on the link, the "your ad here" boxes should start scrolling, horizontally, to the left. Are you using IE? I haven't tested it there yet and knowing IE, it probably doesn't work.

Comment: Scrolls fine in Chrome for Windows For the record keyframes are css3 and don't work in IE. You may want to rethink how you're doing this.

Comment: Yeah, works okay in Safari too, but not Firefox.

Comment: @RickCalder I thought they worked in IE 9 now?

Comment: Some things do, not positive on keyframes they might. But IE9 still isn't the top dog in the IE users base. Just saying you want to be careful how far ahead you jump in technology, particularly in a situation where you expect to make money from clicks which it appears you do. In those cases you want EVERYONE to be able to see them.

Comment: Oh agreed, which is why this is just testing. Was trying to see if I could get away without using jQuery lol

Comment: My bad, AdBlock was disabling the HTML5 keyframes. It works fine for me now, Chrome in Windows.

Comment: Curious as to why it's not working in Firefox. I have the Moz keyframes..